# AlarmManager fires alarms at wrong time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I managed everything all right to create a notification service used to fire a notification as a result of an alarm. Unfortunately, setting the alarm using AlarmManager doesn't work right. It fires several minutes later (not exactly hours, which would indicate a timezone problem). The recurring period is 1 week, so I used the constant INTERVAL_DAY and multiplied it with 7. In order to make sure that one PendingIntent doesn't replace the other, I pass the dayOfWeek as second parameter to PendingIntent.getService(). I check the correctness of the time for the alarm to fire by logging it:

```
Log.d(TAG, "next alarm " + df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Is there really no way to list all alarms set - at least those from my own app? I believe this is the only way to track down the error.

My code:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
Log.d(TAG, "next alarm " + df.format(cal.getTime()));
Intent showNotificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, dayOfWeek, showNotificationIntent, 0);
getAlarmManager(context).setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    INTERVAL_WEEK, alarmIntent);
```

I want to offer to have an alarm every day, but at various times, which can be set by the user. So I use up to 7 alarms, which should fire on a weekly basis.

Even after reading the numerous answers to similar questions (I don't intend to create a duplicate question), I haven't managed to find the problem.

Comment: Because of setInexactRepeating. Use setRepeating and itr will be processed at the right time.

Comment: In current versions there is no difference between setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating() anymore. Using setRepeating() has always been discouraged by the documentation. It's not about seconds in my app, but the alarm should come within a minute of the set time.

Comment: Yes setRepeating is discouraged because it forces the alarm at a particular time, in either case you want time precision. So the clause here does not hold true.

Comment: Actually, you are right. setRepeating() works fine. As I said, I had expected that "inexact" means that the repeating period isn't exact, but the first alarm is. And the repeating alarms would not be fired by the second, but within a minute. That it can be delayed by several minutes on an idle device came very unexpected to me.

Comment: I agree with you - it **should** be possible to list all scheduled alarms for an application. It's incredibly annoying that there's no API for it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For api levels below 19 you should use `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` and your alarms will trigger exactly at specified time. Thou on api levels 19 and above this will no longer work. There was change in android so that all repeating alarms are inexact. So if you would like to achieve exact repeating alarm you should schedule alarm with `AlarmManager.setExact()` and then when alarm triggers do it again for next week and so on every week.

Comment: I expect inexact repeating to be good enough. It's not about seconds, but the alarm should fire within a minute of the set time, at least when the device is awake and idle. Am I wrong here? Since API level 19 is the one I use as target, there is no difference anyway. I just would expect the alarm to be about as exact as the alarms set in the calendar.

Comment: In api level 19+ `setRepeating()` will be the sam as `setInexactRepeating()` on devices below 19 so be carful about that. With inexact repeating alarm will not happen before it should, but it might occur almost full interval after it should. This will probably not happen with week intervals but something to be careful about. This will depend on other alarms that you have set at similar time on your device.

Comment: Actually, you are right. setRepeating() works fine. As I said, I had expected that "inexact" means that the repeating period isn't exact, but the first alarm is. And the repeating alarms would not be fired by the second, but within a minute. That it can be delayed by several minutes on an idle device came very unexpected to me.

Answer (score 14):

Because of setInexactRepeating. Use setRepeating and it will be processed at the right time.

Instead of:

```
setInexactRepeating
```

use

```
setRepeating
```

setInexactRepeating, is OS and battery friendly, it batches together all the work to be done on Alarm receive and works through one by one, while as setRepeating instantly fires the alarm

Also a note: Alarms are wiped off once phone is rebooted, you might have to implement a boot broadcast receiver to make it persistent. Make sure you dont do that runtime, you need to implement it in the Manifest else when your app is not in background you will not receive any broadcasts.

#### A small example:

**This is working code. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.**

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
...
```

Code:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

**Set Alarm from Service:**

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:**

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

And create new class:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re-setting the alarm after reboot is not the problem, I have already taken care of this. Since I use API level 19 as target, there is no difference between setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating(), but I would expect the alarm to fire within a minute of the set time, at least when the device is awake and idle. Am I wrong here?

Comment: The methods for setRepeating on Android API level 19 have changed, hence setRepeating will not yield the desired result, now there are two ways for you to achieve what you want 1) Set the maximum SDK target and Target SDK version to 18, that will work just fine on 19 or 2) include methods for exact repeating alarm for API level 19. More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: Actually, you are right. setRepeating() works fine. As I said, I had expected that "inexact" means that the repeating period isn't exact, but the first alarm is. And the repeating alarms would not be fired by the second, but within a minute. That it can be delayed by several minutes on an idle device came very unexpected to me.

Comment: The official Docs are not too clear about what and how everything works, somedays ago I was working on Alarm Manager too and due to extensive research and varied sources I came to know of it all. I am planning to post a blog post coming weekend which might be of help to the community. Make sure you keep the maxSDK to 18 if you go the above way.

Comment: Why are you running the receiver in a remote process?

Comment: It is related to my use case to start a new VM using a remote process, because my service runs even when my app does not. Also that I get a new heap in this process. Which is very helpful when my app is intense in context of memory use.