# Android - running app in sleep, polling every N seconds

Tags: android

Is it possible to have an Android app continue to run while the device is asleep, activating or polling every N seconds?

Comment: You can use a service with an alarm manager instead together with a Power Manager, that will be less resource consuming.

Comment: Does this require rooting?

Comment: Not at all, its there to help developers. However please pay attention  to what the docs say when applying all this in API Level 19. This might come handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461191/alarmmanager-fires-alarms-at-wrong-time/21461246#21461246

Answer (score 2):

you can use wake up while the app is in sleep or when the app is unlocked

use this in your manifest file

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

to continue to run while the device is asleep

use the below code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
 wl.acquire();
   ..screen will stay on during this section..
 wl.release();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the way to do it. You have to simply set your scheduled runner via alarm manager to run your application at specified time or after elapsed time.

```
   public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     final public static String ONE_TIME = 'onetime';

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 'YOUR TAG');
         //Acquire the lock
         wl.acquire();
          SetAlarm(context);
   //Release the lock
         wl.release();
     }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
        {
            AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            //After after 5 seconds
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5 , pi); 
        }

    }
```

Remember to add your receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name='com.rakesh.alarmmanagerexample.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver'>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: are there other things that should be set in manifest? does this require rooting