# How to trigger alarmed event in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

IDE: Eclipse,Android/Java Programming.

Hi in android I have 2 applications App1 and App2. Now in App1 I want to setup timer suppose morning 5:00Am. Now I want to run my App2 (5am). Here I want that App1 to automatically trigger(run) the application at particular time.

Please give me some hints What I study to make this work done.

Comment: Although its a broad question and not fit for this site, You need to use an Alarm Manager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461191/alarmmanager-fires-alarms-at-wrong-time/21461246#21461246

Comment: so where to ask this type of questions,explain

Comment: This question is too broad, I would suggest you break it into modules and approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an alarm within app1 that will make a call to a broadcast receiver in app1 that will call an intent to launch app2. The alarm will be registered with the system and will launch your app's broadcast receiver at the time specified. You can make an activity in app2 launchable so that it ca be called from app1 via an intent

AlarmManager documentation for calling events in your app using alarms:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

The Alarm will call a broadcast receiver in your app that you create:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html