# How to send a Notification at a specific time?

Tags: android, eclipse, time, notifications, android-pendingintent

I would like to send a notification at a specific time. Below is my code. Right now, I only get a notification when I start the app, but I do not get a notification at the specified time. Could you help me understand what I am doing wrong.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Trainieren sie jetzt!")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);

    AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, resultPendingIntent);



    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: you have to set the notification where you are setting the time ...

Comment: do You really want repeating alarms?

Comment: Setting a Repeating Alarm with a Broadcast receiver is not a bottle neck as far as I can think of it. Only a timer option can become highly cumbersome. If wake-locks are properly implemented within a service, it becomes all the more efficient.

Comment: but what should i change?

Comment: Also make sure you implement this Alarm through your manifest and listen to Boot Broadcast, in that you have to set your alarm again as at turning off the device your Alarm is wiped.

Comment: You need to Display your Notifications in the onReceive method of your Alarm Class.

Comment: could you post me an example code please?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.con, "Hello from alarm", 1).show(); 


    // System.out.println("Hello from Alarm");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));

}
```

In the above example I am directing the process to my Service class to process my notification, managing wake locks and background service implementation. If you are not implementing a Service you can just display your notifications in the onRecieve method.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461191/alarmmanager-fires-alarms-at-wrong-time/21461246#21461246) it has a complete implementation of the Alarm Class.