# My Alarm Service don't fire

Tags: android, notifications

I have searched in everywhere but I can understand because my Service at a specific time of the day don't fire. Nothing happens.
My code for set up the Alarm:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) act.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(act, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(act, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        // set for 5 seconds later
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+5000, alarmIntent);
```

My code for the Service:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("Alarm worked well");
        Utils.criarNotificacao(context);
    }
}
```

In the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="br.com.blacktoad.q48h2.utils.AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

I can't find any answer.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321443/how-to-start-service-using-alarm-manager-in-android/8321512#8321512

Comment: You ideally `set` it but you dont `setRepeating` my guess! Also there is a difference in how Alarms work pre and post API 18. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461191/alarmmanager-fires-alarms-at-wrong-time/21461246#21461246) out.

Comment: @Skynet You mean: `pre 19 and post 18`.

Comment: Yes Der Golem, my matey :)

Comment: Don't work guys. I used this post too, but nothing.

Comment: I've used "setRepeating", but don't care if I use "set" or "setRepeating".

Answer (score 0):

I find the error!
I need put the:

```
<receiver android:name="br.com.blacktoad.q48h2.utils.AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

in the manifest, but contained in the "application" tag